# How to find the differences in column A in 4 different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have column K in "filter" sheets that need to be compare with column A in "Active_Buy", "Active_Others" and "Active_Make" sheets accordingly.

First it need to be compare with active_buy sheets. if there is value that in column K (filter sheet) but not in column A (active_Buy sheet), then it need to hold that value and compare it with column A (active_others sheets).  If also didnt match, it need to compared with column A (Active_Make sheets).

So, if there is no any match, then the value need to be paste in new sheets name (Unmatched Part No).

I already search everywhere but only can find code that can only compare 2 worksheets only but not more than that.

'Below is the code that i found but only compared two worksheets only
' the concept just same like this but need to hold unmatch value and compare to next worksheet and so on.

```
Sub compare()
    Sheets(3).Activate  'Go to sheet 3
    Cells.Clear         'and clear all previous results

    Range("a1").Select  'set cursor at the top

    Sheets(1).Activate  'go to sheet 1
    Range("a1").Select  'begin at the top

    Dim search_for As String   'temp variable to hold what we need to look for
    Dim cnt As Integer         'optional counter to find out how many rows we found

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""   'repeat the follwoing loop until it reaches a blank row

        search_for = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value   'get a hold of the value in column B

        Sheets(2).Activate  'go to sheet(2)

        On Error Resume Next   'incase what we search for is not found, no errors will stop the macro

        Range("b:b").Find(search_for).Select  'find the value in column B of sheet 2

        If Err <> 0 Then   'If the value was not found, Err will not be zero

            On Error GoTo 0  'clearing the error code

            Sheets(1).Activate   'go back to sheet 1

            r = ActiveCell.Row   'get a hold of current row index

            Range(r & ":" & r).Select  'select the whole row

            cnt = cnt + 1   'increment the counter

            Selection.Copy  'copy current selection

            Sheets(3).Activate  'go to sheet 3

            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll  'Past the entire row to sheet 3

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select  'go down one row to prepare for next row.


        End If
        Sheets(1).Activate   'return to sheet 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select   'go to the next row

    Loop   'repeat

    Sheets(3).Activate    'go to sheet 3 to examine findings

    MsgBox "I have found " & cnt & " rows that did not exist in sheet 2"

End Sub
```

Comment: First step: get rid of all `Select` and `Activate` statements. Then replace all `Selection` objects, incl. `ActiveCell` with `Range` objects. With that done change your code into a function which does one comparison and returns True or False. Then write code to call the function 3 times and take action depending upon what it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sub that takes 2 parameters;

A cell that has the value to search for, and a number indicating the sheet to search in.

When the sub doesn't find the value in neither of the sheets, it adds a new sheet "Unmatched Part No" if it doesn't exist and adds the value that's not found in column A in that sheet:

```
Sub searchSheet(ByVal searchFor As Range, sheetNum As Integer)

    Dim sheetsArr As Variant
    sheetsArr = Array("Active_Buy", "Active_Others", "Active_Make", "Unmatched Part No") 'You can change the names of your sheets here

    If sheetNum = 3 Then   'When we reach the last sheet in our array, then we haven't find a match in neither of the previous sheets

        Dim ws As Worksheet, wsExist As Boolean, lastRow As Integer
        wsExist = False
        'Check if the sheet "Unmatched Part No" exists
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name = sheetsArr(3) Then
                wsExist = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ws

        'If the sheet "Unmatched Part No" doesn't exist add one with this name
        If Not (wsExist) Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetsArr(3)
        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsArr(3)).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column A in the unmatched sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsArr(3)).Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value2 = searchFor.Value2 'append the unfound value in column A
        'MsgBox "New value" & searchFor.Value2 & "appended to 'Unmatched Part No' A" & lastRow + 1
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim search  'Search should be of a variant type to accept errors given by the match function
    search = Application.Match(searchFor.Value2, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsArr(sheetNum)).Range("A:A"), 0)
    If IsError(search) Then searchSheet searchFor, sheetNum + 1  'When match doesn't find the searchFor value, Search is an #N/A error, then search in the next sheet

End Sub
```

And you need another sub to call the first one passing each cell of column K of filter sheet to the first sub. Here it is:

```
Sub lookInSheets()

    Dim lastRw As Integer, ctrlCol As Range
    lastRw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("filter").Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row   'To abbreviate the search to just the filled cells in column K
    Set ctrlCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("filter").Range("K1:K" & lastRw)

    For Each ctrlCell In ctrlCol
        searchSheet ctrlCell, 0
    Next ctrlCell

End Sub
```

Copy both subs in a new module and run the second one to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a For Each loop to run through the values on the 'Filter' sheet, set ranges on each of the other sheets, then check in each of the ranges. I've tested this code and it seems to do the trick. I've commented so you can see what's going on at each line.

(You'll need to adjust the sheet names to match you own, and adjust Application settings to make things run faster if you've got a lot of data.)

```
Sub compareColumns()

Dim lastRow1, lastRowAB, lastRowAO, lastRowAM, lastRowUMPN As Long
Dim rng1, rngAB, rngAO, rngAM As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim found As Range

' Define our last rows for each sheet
lastRow1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilterSheet").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowAB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveBuy").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowAO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveOthers").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowAM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveMake").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowUMPN = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UnmatchedPartNo").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Set the ranges that we'll loop through
Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilterSheet").Range("K1:K" & lastRow1)
Set rngAB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveBuy").Range("A1:A" & lastRowAB)
Set rngAO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveOthers").Range("A1:A" & lastRowAO)
Set rngAM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveMake").Range("A1:A" & lastRowAM)

' Loop through each cell in the filtered sheet
For Each cell In rng1
    ' Try to find the value in ActiveBuy sheet
    Set found = rngAB.Find(cell.Value)
    ' If not found, try the next sheet
    If found Is Nothing Then
        Set found = rngAO.Find(cell.Value)
        ' If not found, try the next sheet
        If found Is Nothing Then
            Set found = rngAM.Find(cell.Value)
            ' If still not found, copy to the value to the 'Unmatched Parts' sheet
            If found Is Nothing Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UnmatchedPartNo").Range("A" & lastRowUMPN + 1).Value = cell.Value
                MsgBox "I have found a value " & cell.Value & " that did not exist in any sheets."
            End If
        End If
    End If
' Reset 'found' to equal nothing for the next loop
Set found = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I already try your code and its working. but i dont want it to appear in message box cause there i set the limit that user can enter until K500 for column K. so if user just enter 10 data in column K then its only have 3 unmatched data, then i need to click many time the message box. Therefore i just want it to be paste in UnmatchedPartNo sheets.

Comment: i already delete the code line --> MsgBox.......  but then it cannot paste the value of unmatched data in UnmatchedPartNo Sheets.

Comment: i hope you will notice my comment :)

Comment: The user won't have to enter a limit; the lastRow code will automatically run until the final row in each column :-)  If you delete the MsgBox line then the code will still work and will list all missing parts. I only left the MsgBox in there because I thought you might want it. Feel free to delete.

Comment: i already delete the message box but it does not paste the unmatched value. is it because the line before message box code = cell only ?

Comment: Yes, it will only paste the cell value. If you need the entire row then you could replace "= cell" with "=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilterSheet").Range..." and then input the range you want to copy across.

Comment: You are most welcome - and thanks to @NadNone for the edit. Just for reference, here is more complete example of what you might be looking for regarding copying the whole row across. Replace the whole "=cell.Value" line with this: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilterSheet").Range("K" & cell.Row & ":Z" & cell.Row).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UnmatchedPartNo").Range("A" & lastRowUMPN) If you found the answer useful please consider giving it an upvote :-)